# How to programmatically synthesize a sound?

Tags: java, python, audio

I want to implement a simple synth instrument that plays sounds of certain frequencies. What are the best ways to do that in Python or Java?

Comment: Take a look at Project 2 on this site: http://beastie.cs.ua.edu/cs250/

Comment: Here's a summary of the Python packages available for audio generation and processing: http://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio You can also look into the Java Sound API: http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/sound/techReference/javasoundfaq.html